# how to get array of array from post meta data in wordpress

Tags: arrays, wordpress, var

I want to get property locations from post meta data fields and display it on map dynamically,in Below code i took static  locations.how to get these  values ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3] dynamically.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

var locations = [

  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.923036,151.28747820854187),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1],locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
     infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }

  })(marker, i));
 }

 </script>
```

i want to get those locations   from post meta data fields.any  help appreciated..

Comment: do you want it in PHP or JS?

Comment: i am doing this in wordpress template .i want to get that coordinates data from meta data of wordpress post. is there any way to get that.

Comment: get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'addr_coordiates', true); i used this previously to get post data .how to get all post meta data values from all posts as an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add posts array with you desired arguments and collect all the coordinates.

```
$allPosts = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 20
));
$getCord = [];
if ( $allPosts ) {
    foreach ( $allPosts as $post ) :
        $getCord[] = get_post_meta($post->ID,'addr_coordiates', true);
    endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

In Javascript:

```
<script>
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($getCord);?>
</script>
```

Comment: as your suggestion i added code but coordinates are not getting by  using  echo i return values it is showing  as ArrayArray ,by using index getting individual values..please help me out at any  cost i have to finish this task..please check below code in place of  var locations i want dynamic values

Comment: i have edited my code please check once and give me solution for that

Comment: @Bala. Edited my answer. Can you print `$getCord` and let me know what its showing now

Comment: in alert getting coordinates as an array [34.028249, 151.157507,34.0282849, 123.157507] like this how to get latitude,langitude  as array please check my code oncevar locations =  <?php echo json_encode($getCord);?>;
     alert(locations);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    });
   var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]),
        map: map}); in place of position not getting coordinates,if give static values  marker is showing.

Comment: getting  array as [ -34.028249, 151.157507, -34.028249, 151.157507, -34.028249, 151.157507,],i want to split 2 coordinates

Comment: @Bala You mean like above array you mentioned in question ?

Comment: yes,but i am getting all latitude,langitude values as array

Comment: i did not understand,by giving two values latitude & langitude map showing marker  var locations = <?php echo json_encode($getCord);?>;

Comment: First, Can you get all lat long and required meta data??? And update you question. so that I can make an array of all these